# Flutter - app-debug.apk is getting uploaded in github

Tags: git, flutter, dart

I'm getting the following warnings every time I make a push to my git repo

```
remote: warning: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: warning: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: warning: File build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk is 63.00 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 
MB
```

These are from my .gitignore file

```
# Flutter/Dart/Pub related
**/doc/api/
**/ios/Flutter/.last_build_id
.dart_tool/
.flutter-plugins
.flutter-plugins-dependencies
.packages
.pub-cache/
.pub/
/build/
```

Additionally I've added the following line to get through the situation

```
build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk
```

Everything seems fine, yet app-debug.apk is getting pushed every time. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Try `flutter clean` before committing to git.

Comment: didn't help!! Not able to solve this issue still.

Comment: Actually, I believe, this should work.. because, after `flutter clean` build directory will not there at all..so, no debug APK. Or..do you still see build directory even after flutter clean..?

Comment: It worked man. Thanks. Please post this as an answer, so I can approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `flutter clean` before committing to git.

because, after `flutter clean`, `build` directory will not be there at all..so, no debug APK.

Answer (score 0):

Having same issue but this didn't solve the issue as I can't even locate the uploaded APK on directories even after deleting them and running `flutter clean`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31767481)